# regular expression that will allow only digit(0-9),single comma(,) and multiple dot(.).example : 10.000.100,00--valid 10,000,100.00--invalid

Tags: java, regex

i need a regular expression that will allow only number(0-9),single comma(,) and multiple dot(.).

example : 10.000.100,00--valid
        10,000,100.00--invalid

i have tried

1. ^[\d.,]+$
2. \d+,?.*

but none of them works. both of them are allowing multiple comma.

need help for this regular expression in java.

Comment: i have included the example expressions that i tried.but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one: `^\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:,\d+)?$`

It ensures that there can be at most one comma, and that such a comma must be preceded by at least one digit and followed by at least one digit, however the comma is optional.

It also ensures that any periods occur before the comma (if present), and that there is no leading trailing, or consecutive commas.

Valid inputs:

```
10.000.100,00
10.000.100
100
```

Invalid inputs:

```
10,000,100.00
10.000.100,0.0
10.000.100,
10.000.
.10.000
10..100
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hSjM2X/1) for demo.

Comment: this expression fails with this sample data.  11.22,33.44 . ....this input has single comma and multiple dots. it should allow this. @Andreas

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury Sorry. Your examples made it look like normal number formatting, where there are no dots following the comma. **Taking your description literally**, use `^(?=.)[\d.]*(?:,[\d.]*)?$`. At most one comma (optional), any number of digits (optional) and dots (optional), in any order, i.e. dots can be leading, trailing, and together, but must be at least one character, doesn't matter if that is a digit, dot, or comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this expression:-  `^\d+[\d.]*,?[\d.]*\d*$`
It will allow start and end with digit.  multiple (.) dots and a single (,) comma

Link :- https://regex101.com/r/hSjM2X/7

Comment: No need to bracket the comma, `,?` is fine. No need to escape dot inside character class, `[\d.]*` is fine.

Comment: but if in input only 0 or only 1 this expression return false this should not be @Tarun . try with this ^\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:,\d+)?$ as Andress suggested.

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury 00.000.00,00 and 1.111,1.1 are matching from this, Check link

Comment: @tarun but it should also return true if you input a single digit without any dot or comma.that was my point.

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury check now